# get models name and count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I have this in `models_name`:

```
model_names = Object.constants.collect { |sym| Object.const_get(sym) }.select { |constant| constant.class == Class && constant.include?(Mongoid::Document) }.collect { |klass| klass.name }
```

the result is:

```
["Model_name1","Model_name2","Model_name3"]
```

I need something like:

```
[{"Model1":"Count"},{"Model2":"Count"},{"Model3":"Count"}]
```

I need show in a chart all models and object counter inside each model is working with `morris.js`

You can see the example:

http://jsbin.com/uzosiq/2/embed?javascript,live

Thank you very much!

Comment: confused about "object number". what do you mean by this?

Comment: i assume you need the number of instances of each model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that last one:

```
collect { |klass| klass.name }
```

rewrite it as

```
collect { |klass| [klass.name, klass.count] }
```

this should return an array of arrays of 2 elements (classname and count). If the variable to which this is assigned is called a, just do this:

```
Hash[a]
```

now you have a hash at your disposal. Now you can do this:

```
Hash[a].map do |k, v|
  {k => v}
end
```

and now you have an array of hashes of only one key-value assoc each. Which I think it is what you want.

Comment: Thank you is possible remove embeds models from array? I get error with embed model with mongoid

Comment: I didn't understand exactly what you mean, but yes, you can remove elements from arrays by applying #reject with a condition: http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#M000434

Comment: Thank you I need remove the model with name "RatingMark"

Answer (score 0):

```
module Foo

end

class Bar
  include Foo
end

1.upto(5) { Bar.new }

model_names = Object.constants.collect { |sym| Object.const_get(sym) }.
  select { |constant| constant.class == Class && constant.include?(Foo) }.
  inject({}) do |m,klass|
    m.update klass.name => ObjectSpace.each_object(klass).to_a.size
  end

p model_names

{"Bar"=>5}
```

### Will work only on MRI based rubies, so no jRuby nor Runbinius.

### [Here is a live demo](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?lang=ruby&file=get-models-name-and-count.rb&versions=1.8.7-p370+1.9.2-p320+1.9.3-p286+2.0.0-preview1+ree-1.8.7-2012.02&run=true)